# Is `activator dist` sufficient in order to deploy a Play app?

Tags: playframework, typesafe-activator

I wonder whether `activator dist` is sufficient to deploy a Play app? Should `activator clean compile` be run as well? I have read the [Deploying documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Deploying#Using-the-dist-task), but it is not clear to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running `dist` already compiles the project and it is enough yes. Cleaning before should not be needed. If you want to run the tests first run: `sbt test dist`.

The output of `dist` is at `target/universal/project-name.zip`, just unzip its contents to the production server. You probably want to use a different configuration file for your production server, so you will run the app like this: `./bin/project-name -Dconfig.file=conf/production.conf`.

If you want to build a fat jar instead with all the necessary dependencies take a look at [sbt assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly).

Comment: I prefer to use clean before deploying to production. Sometimes weird stuff happens with the dependencies :)